# Check proof that two functions are linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I am not very experienced with math and need help with a proof. I need to show that the pair of functions $t$ and $1/t$ defined for $t>0$ are linearly independent. Is the following a sufficient proof? If so, is there a simpler way?

Assume $at+b\frac{1}{t}=0$ is correct for any $t>0$. Substituting $t=1$ yields $a+b=0$ (Eq. 1). Substituting $t=2$ yields $2a+\frac{b}{2}=0$ (Eq. 2). Subtracting Eq. 1 from Eq. 2 yields $a-\frac{b}{2}=0$, so $a=\frac{b}{2}$. Substituting $a=\frac{b}{2}$ into Eq. 1 yields $\frac{3}{2}b=0$, therefore $b=0$, which implies $a=0$.

Since the only scalars $a, b$ such that $at+b\frac{1}{t}=0$ are $a=b=0$ then $t$ and $1/t$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Proof is fine  :)

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is fine and straightforward.

Maybe little shorter proof would be to see that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} at+b\frac{1}t$ can be zero if and only if $a=0$. It follows immediately that $b=0$ too.

Comment: Thanks! Oh yeah I was wondering about that but forgot to ask! Nice and simple.

Answer (score -2):

Well they are actually not linear independent. Take $t=1$ and $a=1;b=-1$

and You have $1+(-1*1/1$)

@billiam Thanks for your answer, if it is only positive, then it is quite trivial, here is my previous answer. Well, I don't know whether it may help, but since $t>0;1/t>0$ therefore $t+1/t$ can only be zero if the coefficients are zero.

But i could prove that $1/t$ is at least poaitive. first lets show that if $0<x |*x \Leftrightarrow0<x^2$ so the sqaure is always positive. Now $0<t|*(1/t)^2\Leftrightarrow0* (1/t)^2<t*(1/t)^2 \Leftrightarrow0<1/t$ hope that helps

For any positive scalars the functions as it takes only positive values is positive again.

Comment: I think that it would have to hold for all values of t (greater than zero).